# AngularJS promise get data in foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have promise for getting data:

```
var activeUsersByZonePromise = function (zone) {
            return $http.get(backendUri.buildAppUri('/active_users/total', {
                'start_day': $scope.timeFilter.startDay(),
                'zone': zone
            })).then(function (data) {
                return {
                    count: data.data.activeUsers.current,
                    sincePreviousTime: data.data.activeUsers.current - data.data.activeUsers.previous,
                    arrow: arrowImage(data.data.activeUsers.current, data.data.activeUsers.previous)
                };
            });
        };
```

And after it I heed build some data models, and I use foreach for set value and get data, like this:

```
getZonesPromise.then(function (result) {
            var zones = [];
            angular.forEach(result.qualityScore.zones, function (response) {
                zones.push({
                    zone: response.zone,
                    qualityScore: response.qualityScore,
                    prevQualityScore: response.prevQualityScore
                });
            });
            return zones;
        }).then(function (zones) {
            var data = [];
            angular.forEach(zones, function (zone) {
                data.push({
                    title: zone.zone,
                    activeUsers: activeUsersByZonePromise(zone.zone),
                    //...

      $scope.zonesDataModel = data;
    });
```

And activeUsersByZonePromise(zone.zone) can't get data,because zonesDataModel I use for data-binding , help me lease fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getZonesPromise.then(function (result) {
            var zones = [];
            angular.forEach(result.qualityScore.zones, function (response) {
                zones.push({
                    zone: response.zone,
                    qualityScore: response.qualityScore,
                    prevQualityScore: response.prevQualityScore
                });
            });
            return zones;
        }).then(function (zones) {
            $scope.zonesDataModel = [];
            angular.forEach(zones, function (zone) {
                activeUsersByZonePromise(zone.zone).then(function(user) {
                    $scope.zonesDataModel.push({
                        title: zone.zone,
                        activeUsers: user,
                    //...
                }
    });
```

you assign promise `activeUsersByZonesPromise` result to `activeUsers`.
This way seems better